# Realloc pointer in C++ that was malloced() in C

Tags: c++, c, malloc, interop, realloc

I'm writing a library in `C++` that is supposed to interop with other `C` code/libraries.

If a client passes an array that was `malloc()`'d in `C` into a library function, can the `C++` function safely call `realloc()` on that memory block and return it (leaving it up to the `C` caller to `free()` it?

Or does `C++` use a different implementation and bookkeeping than `C` and they are incompatible.

Here's some example code:

### C code:

c_header.h:

```
struct my_list {
  int count;
  int capacity;
  long* array;
};
```

c_code.c:

```
#include "c_header.h"
#include "ccp_header.h"

int some_method() {
  struct my_list list1;
  list1.count = 0;
  list1.array = malloc(sizeof(long)*5);
  list1.capacity = 5;
  int ret = cpp_extend_list(&list1) // todo: error checking etc...
  free(list1.array);
}
```

### C++ code:

```
#include "c_header.h"

int cpp_extend_list(struct my_list *list) {
  long* temp = realloc(list->array, sizeof(long) * (list->capacity + 10));
  if (!temp) return -1;
  list->array = temp;
  list->capacity+=10;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The library function would *always* have to return the same or new pointer, but in C it would *not* always be safe, since internal pointer references in your data structures can become invalid. The caller would have to detect a change in memory location and change all the internal references. Horrible. Especially since pointer arithmetic between the new location and a separate object (now non-existent) isn't defined.

Comment: @WeatherVane The function actually takes a pointer to a struct containing the array pointer. The struct address is not being changed, and all access to the array is done via the containing struct, so there should be no problem on that front.

Comment: In that case please post the specific code in question, which otherwise can only be answered generally. And note that `realloc` **can** change the address, which cannot be predicted.

Comment: @WeatherVane of course `realloc` can change the address. But the caller doesn't care because it always access the array through the containers pointer (which will be updated after `realloc`). I'll try to post a sample.

Comment: It is an error, because `realloc` does not take `sizeof(long)` into account. It should be `realloc(list->array, (list->capacity + 10) * sizeof(long))`. Is this why you think it isn't safe?

Comment: @WeatherVane no. that was just a bug caused by typing quickly. My reason to think it's not safe is explained in the question - maybe the `C++` standard `realloc` is a completely different implementation than `C`s.

Comment: At least in the GNU world, the standard C++ library links to the standard C library, and `realloc` is in the standard C library.